# CentOS LDAP authentication

Tags: linux, ldap

How to configure LDAP-auth in CentOS 6?

I configured it using GUI tool. Configuration looks  like this :

[image]

But when I logout from root and try login with user defined in LDAP  - nothing happens. I use standard CentOS auth window, choose "Other...", then type username and password, **but after typing password it say *"Authentication failure"* and return me to startup window where I can choose some system user or choose again "Other..." user.**

P.S. LDAP server is running on same machine (and works fine). I try to login with user with DN: `cn=username,cn=groupname,dc=mydomain,dc=com` (i.e. user located under Base DN `dc=mydomain,dc=com`)

In `/var/log/secure`  I found this messages:

> error retrieving information about user myuser1

....

> error looking up user information for: myuser1

Comment: What is being logged to the log files ?

Comment: @topdog I Updated question

Comment: I can't help but notice that LARGE error message at the top of the GUI dialog. Have you actually verified that PAM is able to connect to the LDAP service on that box versus the LDAPS service?